# Unable to set default value for checkbox form element inside tableselect

Tags: 7, forms

I've created a custom table using a `tableselect` element, and within each row, I have a [checkbox](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#checkbox) form element that should populate the checkbox from a checkbox field in the node. I've tried every possible format of `#default_value` (setting it to `1`, `array(1)`, etc), to no avail. Since in HTML it's the `checked` attribute that causes a checkbox to show as checked, I came up with this option:

```
  foreach($translations as $locale => $locale_data) {
    // Get data for other fields...

    // Get data for Staging Only checkbox
    $staging_only = isset($entity->field_pub_staging_only[$locale]) ? (int)$entity->field_pub_staging_only[$locale][0]['value'] : 0;

    $row = array(
     'language_locale' => $locale_link,
     'status' => $status,
     'stage_url' => $stage_url,
     'start_date' => array(
       'data'=> array(
         '#type'=>'textfield',
         '#value'=> $new_start_date,
         '#title' => 'Start Date',
         '#title_display'=>'invisible',
         '#name'=> 'start_date[' . $locale . ']',
         '#id'=>  'start-date[' . $locale . ']',
         '#attributes' => array('class' => array('datepicker')),
         '#size' => 10,
         '#maxlength' => 10
       ),
     ),
     'end_date' => array(
       'data'=> array(
         '#type'=>'textfield',
         '#value'=> $new_end_date,
         '#title' => 'End Date',
         '#title_display'=>'invisible',
         '#name'=> 'end_date[' . $locale . ']',
         '#id'=> 'end-date[' . $locale . ']',
         '#attributes' => array('class' => array('datepicker')),
         '#size' => 10,
         '#maxlength' => 10
       ),
     ),
      'staging_only' => array(
        'data'=> array(
          '#type'=>'checkbox',
          '#title' => 'Staging Only',
          '#title_display'=>'invisible',
          '#name'=> 'staging_only[' . $locale . ']',
          '#id'=> 'staging_only[' . $locale . ']',
          '#default_value' => $staging_only
        ),
      ),
      'display_title' => $title
    );

    if ($staging_only) {
      $row['staging_only']['data']['#attributes'] = array('checked' => array('checked'));
    }

    $options[$locale] = $row;
  }

  $header = array(
    'language_locale' => t('Language Locale'),
    'status' => t('Status'),
    'stage_url' => t('Stage URL'),
    'start_date' => t('Start Date'),
    'end_date' => t('End Date'),
    'staging_only' => t('Staging Only'),
    'display_title' => t('Display Title')
  );

  $form['table'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $options,
    '#empty' => t('No content available.'),
    '#attributes' => array('id' => array('locale-table')),
  );

...

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type'=>'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
  );

  return $form;
}
```

where I'm basically manually added the `checked` attribute to the element when it's checked. It works, but it seems sort of hackish, since it's not using what would normally be used to set a form element value with Form API. Is there a better way to do this with the usual Form API settings?

**CLARIFICATION** It appears that my question wasn't clear, based on the answers I've received so far. The issue is not whether the tableselect row checkbox is checked by default; the issue is attempting to mark as checked the `staging_only` checkbox, which is a separate from api element within the tableselect row.

Answer (score 1):

I remember struggling with this for a moment ! The documentation is not so explicit..

The *tableselect* element takes a `#default_value` array as a multiple *select* element would do, that is at the same level as the `#options` array, and with each selected option key being mapped to a truthy value, usually integer `1`.

In the foreach, you would do something like this :

```
if ($staging_only) {
  // $row['staging_only']['data']['#attributes'] = array('checked' => array('checked'));
  $selection[$locale] = 1;
}
```

And then :

```
$form['table'] = array(
  '#type' => 'tableselect',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#options' => $options,
  '#default_value' => $selection,
  '#empty' => t('No content available.'),
  '#attributes' => array('id' => array('locale-table'))
);
```

Non present options in the selection array default to false so you can ignore unchecked values.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `#default_value` key of the form. This key will reference an array of the same shape as the values in `$form_state`, which will have only the rows checked. Each item will have a key the same as its value, these keys/values will be the key of each row in the table. Sounds complicated but it is not. Check these two examples.

**Rows with sequential key**

```
$rows =  [
  [ 1, 'first value'], // row 0
  [ 2, 'first value'], // row 1
];

// will select the first row
$selection = [0 => 0];

$form['table'] = [
  '#type' => 'tableselect',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#options' => $rows,
  '#default_value' => $selection,
  '#empty' => t('No content available.'),
  '#attributes' => ['id' => ['locale-table']]
];
```

**Rows as an associative array**

```
$rows =  [
  'r11' => [ 123, 'first value'], // row 0
  'k22' => [ 243, 'first value'], // row 1
];

// will select the first row and the second row
$selection = [
  'r11' => 'r11',
  'k22' => 'k22',
];
```