# Override one line in core tabelselect jQuery behavior so custom checkboxes aren't affected

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

I have created a custom table using a Form API [tableselect](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#tableselect) element, and within my table, I have embedded a checkbox form element that is checked based on an entity field (see [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273451/unable-to-set-default-value-for-checkbox-form-element-inside-tableselect) for details). The checkbox functionality works fine. The problem I've discovered, though, is that the `Select/Unselect All` checkbox that is created as the first column in the table also affects my custom checkboxes, in that when I click on the select/unselect all checkbox, it also selects/unselects all the checkboxes in my column.

The offending code is in the [tableselect jQuery behavior](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/misc/tableselect.js?h=7.x), and it's one line that makes the assumption that the only checkbox a tableselect element will ever have is the one that is part of the element:

```
if ($(event.target).is('input:checkbox')) {
  // Loop through all checkboxes and set their state to the select all checkbox' state.
  checkboxes.each(function () {
    this.checked = event.target.checked;
    // Either add or remove the selected class based on the state of the check all checkbox.
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
  });
  // Update the title and the state of the check all box.
  updateSelectAll(event.target.checked);
}
```

As the comment says, it does all checkboxes. Sigh.

From what I've been reading, my only option is to use [hook_js_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7.x) to replace the behavior with my own version. However, that seems like a bit of overkill just to change a couple lines. Is there another way to keep this behavior from affecting my checkbox field, or am I understanding correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing what I suggested, and overriding with my own custom version of `tableselect.js`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_js_alter().
 */
function language_dashboard_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  // Override core tableselect.js with custom version.
  $javascript['misc/tableselect.js']['data'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'language_dashboard') . '/js/language_dashboard_tableselect.js';
}
```

just to tweak this one line from this:

```
checkboxes = $('td input:checkbox:enabled', table).click(function (e)
```

to this:

```
checkboxes = $('td input:checkbox:enabled', table).not("input[id*='staging_only']").click(function (e)
```

by adding the `.not()` selector. It seems like a lot of code copying just for that one modification, but as of now, I don't see any other way.